# How to add controls and buttons to map?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

This is probably a really basic question, but I can't figure it out. I'm building a map using D3. My code creates and svg, appends a g element to it and then draws the map within it. What I want is to render a set of buttons and controls that are positioned inside the map viewer. They would be zoom buttons, a dropdown to display different sets of data and a timeline slider.

For example, with the dropdown selector I want placed I did this:

I tried using d3 as in:

```
svg.append("select")
  .attr("class", "field_dropdown")
  .data(['housing_unit', 'tenure', 'median_contract_rent', 'median_value', 'median_income'])
  .enter()
  .append("option")
  .attr("value", function(d) {
       return d
   });
```

but this rendered the select item and option items separate from each other, and not even visible within the map container.

As mentioned, not only do I wanna add a dropdown, but also buttons for zoom and a slider, among other items. How do I render and position them in the map container?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This has been asked several times (surely a duplicate): you **cannot** append HTML elements ("div", "p", "select", "h1" etc) to an SVG. It will simply not work.

The best solution, in your case, is creating the drop down menu and the other controls outside the SVG, in the HTML.

But, if you really want to create this drop down inside the SVG (which I don't advise), you can use `foreignObject` (which will not work on IE):

```
var foreign = svg.append("foreignObject")
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 100)
    .append("xhtml:body");

var select = foreign.append('select')
    .attr("class", "field_dropdown")
    //the rest of your code
```